# Windows 10 reading from multiple SOFTWARE registry hives simultaneously?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I had an issue with a few startup programs that weren't starting at startup. Google back-up-and-sync and Dropbox. They were both marked as enabled in CCleaner.

When opening the startup tab in windows 10 task manager, things got stranger. Google was listed but dropbox not. In the Google BU-and-Sync preferences, when I toggled the checkbox to run at startup, the row in the task manager startup tab would correctly disappear and appear instantly and accordingly. But with Dropbox, it would never even appear.

So I decided to do more digging and went to the startup items in CCleaner, and right-clicked to choose "open in regedit..."

Each time I did this with a different startup item, it opened regedit in multiple tabs and that's when I realized that it seemed as if I had two versions of the SOFTWARE HIVE in the registry.

When opening regedit from the windows search bar, it opens a different SOFTWARE hive than when opening the registry from CCleaner (see screenshot below - both paths are the same.)

**But as you see in the screenshot below, I only have ONE software hive in any given view of the registry.**

NOTE: I have not been able to replicate this on any other 3rd party registry managers or autorun software. When opening the registry to a startup item via all other 3rd party software, it opens the default registry - same as if I were to manually open regedit. Can someone experiment with CCleaner and try to replicate this issue?

Can someone please explain to me what's going on?

[image: Image 01]

[image: Image 02]

When comparing HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist from both results, the entries look identical:

[image: hiveset]

Comment: Could you compare `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist` from both views? And was CCleaner installed from Windows Store?

Comment: @user1686 both hiveset entries look identical. I added a screenshot in my question to show you this. I also showed my config folder. CCleaner is the standalone software - not from Windows store.

Comment: I think harrymc answered your question. This is not abnormal behavior in Windows, especially Windows 10 and how it manages multiple accounts. Regarding your startup issues with some programs, you can solve them with one of two methods: copy-paste their *shortcut* ("Paste shortcut") in the "shell:common startup" folder you'll access via the Run box, or create a new task in Computer Management. I usually choose the first method because it's quicker, but you must have admin rights for both.

Comment: My question is not why I have multiple files in the config folder. My question is how can my startup programs be located in separate software hives. When Windows reads the "run" key to determine which programs run at startup, it seems that my run entries are split into multiple SOFTWARE hives. Is this possible? Furthermore, we should have the freedom to vote as we feel right. For harrymc to downvote my question just because I downvoted his answer curropts the voting system.

Comment: Please address your questions to Microsoft. We are not Microsoft developers and cannot help with explaining why and how they do things. I deleted my answer that you didn't like which explained that this is normal, but this is really all you need to know.

Comment: @harrymc This comment can be applied to every single question on the StackExchange Forums.

Comment: No it doesn't. Believe me, I have some experience in this.

Comment: My question is not why I have multiple files in the config folder. My question Why is  Windows 10 reading from multiple SOFTWARE registry hives simultaneously?

Comment: I don't care how Microsoft does things. If they want to read from multiple hives, that's fine but how am I supposed to manage my registry if I can't access those hives without CCleaner? the way I understand is that when you open regedit, you should be seeing everything that Windows is using and you shouldn't have to guess and load different hives to achieve what you need.

Comment: @harrymc Your answer didn't address my main questions and that's why I downvoted and that's why you deleted your answer. But by downvoting my question out of spite, that's just abusing the voting system. Please reverse the downvote for the sake of others who might have this issue or others that might want to help.

Comment: Downvoting people who try to help and spent some time on writing up an answer can also be construed as an act of spite. But I downvoted your answer after you made it clear that you are asking for information that only a Microsoft developer can have. It's also very very vague as question.

Comment: On the Microsoft page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/256986/windows-registry-information-for-advanced-users they do not mention that entries can be split into multiple hives with the same name (eg: software) They mention that to edit the registry you go to regedit. Well, as I mentioned in my question, when I go to regedit, I don't see all the entries (as I explained, CCleaner opens a different software hive where more startup entries are present.) So how an I supposed to access all the startup entried with regedit?

Comment: I think this is a good question that's never been asked before. don't down vote because you don't have an answer. The question is clear and they have done research to prove it is a legitimate question.

Comment: Not sure if this explains things or not>"If you open Registry Editor in Windows 10, you will get the registry hives of current user only. If there are multiple user accounts on the computer, you will need to login to each account to see, edit and change the registry settings of each user.">>>>https://www.itechtics.com/edit-registry-settings-other-users/

Comment: @Moab good thinking. However, I am the only user of the PC so everything installed would be under my user name. So what I don't understand is why when I open a startup item in regedit via CCleaner, it opens it up in a supposedly different software hive.

Comment: There are other user default user accounts even though you only created one, and they have ntuser.dat hives in them, better question is where the hell is ccleaner loading its registry hive from.

Comment: @harrymc Please see my posted answer and please consider reversing the downvote on the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer elsewhere. I'll post it here to benefit others:

You are quite correct, there ARE two different SOFTWARE hives.

One is a 32-bit registry hive, the other 64-bit. Which you see in Regedit depends on whether you are running the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Regedit. I suspect in your case CCleaner is opening the 32-bit version of Regedit, while Start launches 64-bit Regedit. Actually, 64-bit Regedit can show you both SOFTWARE hives....

While the 32-bit Regedit is redirected to show that 32-bit hive as if its the only SOFTWARE hive.

https://support.microsoft.com/help/305097/how-to-view-the-system-registry-by-using-64-bit-versions-of-windows

To see this for yourself you can run the 32 and 64-bit versions of Regedit at the same time. Open the default 64-bit Regedit from the Start menu. Then use WinKey+R to bring up the Run box and run the 32-bit Regedit with: `%systemroot%\syswow64\regedit -m` (the **-m** switch allows you to run a second instance of Regedit).

[image: regedit compare x32 x64]